# argparse args.accumulate isn't being recognised as a valid attribute in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, arguments, command-line-arguments, argparse

Context:
I am attempting to make a Youtube command line video downloader as a small project for myself to understand python better. I am using argparse to get the args from the command line.

Issue: When I ran it the error came up `AttributeError: 'Namespace' object has no attribute 'accumulate'` How can I fix this?

Python Version: 3.10

OS: Windows 11

```
...

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Download a Youtube video')
parser.add_argument('video_url', type=str, help='Type a URL for a YouTube video.')
parser.add_argument('save_dir', type=str, help='Type the directory you want the YouTube video to be saved to be saves.')
args = parser.parse_args()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    video_url = args.accumulate(args.video_url)
    save_dir = args.accumulate(args.save_dir)
    print(video_url, save_dir)
```

I am doing this because it said this in the docs https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/argparse.html

Comment: Where do you get the idea that `accumulate` would be a valid attribute? `args.accumulate`.  You don't define an `argument` with that name.  `print(args)` should show you what attributes are valid.  The `args.accumulate(args.integers)` in the first example is only valid because there's an `argument` with a `dest='accumulate'.

Comment: @hpaulj Ah I see my error now. Thank you for the insight I have fixed it.